# How to deal with the return type of RealmSwift function calls

Tags: ios, swift, bson

When using the RealmSwift package and calling atlas functions like this:

```
// user is the RLMUser
let result = try await user.functions.functionName([AnyBSON("functionArgument")])
```

the result looks something like this:

```
document(["status": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.int32(200)), "request": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.document(["_last": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.bool(true)), "upgradeOrConnect": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.bool(false)) ...
```

In my case the underlying document has around 50 key value pairs with nested documents. I am very confused as to what would be the suggested way to convert this into some Swift object or use these values without manually typing each key and using something like:

```
if let bson = result as? RealmSwift.AnyBSON,
   let finishReason = bson.value(forKey: "someKeyName") as? String {
    // Process 
} else {
    // Handle the case where the result is not in the expected format
}
```

---

Surely there must be some way to convert this with some simple function? I have tried

```
let bsonData = try BSONSerialization.data(from: bsonDocument)
let decoder = BSONDecoder()
```

but this throws the error "Cannot find 'BSONSerialization' in scope"

Comment: https://tech.iheart.com/using-realm-with-swift-and-codable-10a825042e63

Comment: I am now using `JSON.stringify( ... )` in my function and then converting back to JSON in swift using `JSONSerialization`. Is this an efficient way of doing this?